# Formula for nonlinear / logarithmic slider, keeping 100% at centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, zooming, logarithm

I am attempting to build a nonlinear horizontal zoom slider for my app, and I am struggling to find the right formula for the 'nonlinearity'. The zoom should be a percentage (higher or lower) of the 'original' width, with 100% (default) in the centre. The percentage range should be from 10% to 10000%. The slider itself has a range from 10 to 4000, with a default value of 2000 keeping it centred:

```
<input type="range" id="zoom" min="10" max="4000" value="2000" autocomplete="off">
```

My current JS formula does the following (where `val` is the slider's current value):

```
Math.floor(Math.pow(10, parseInt(val)/1000));
```

This is OK, and nicely places 100% at the slider centre, but the graduation on either side is too steep.

What I want, ideally, is a linear or near-linear change from 10% to 100% (so that 50% is at roughly the quarter-way mark), and then a non-linear, logarithmic change from 100% to 1000%, while still keeping 100% at the slider centre. Is there a formula for this, or do I actually have to build what I just described, computing linear values from 0 to the the centre, and logarithmic values from the centre to the end?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz0swyze/).

Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: Probably not much better, but something to consider: `10+Math.min(9990,0|(100*Math.tan(v/8000*Math.PI)))`

Comment: @unholybear Thank you, that's actually a really nice way of doing it, especially for the 10-100 side.